# MySQL 5.7.11 mysql_secure_installation don't work

Tags: mysql

Linux version: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 
Server version: 5.7.11 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Download from the link below:
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/

When I try to run `mysql_secure_installation`
I set the password and reload all the tasks done.
but When I try to login the mysql, It doesn't require the password for the root user.

```
>>>mysql 


mysql> select * from user;
+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+----    ---------+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+-----------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------+--------------+------------------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+----------------+
| Host      | User      | Select_priv | Insert_priv | Update_priv | Delete_priv | Create_priv | Drop_priv | Reload_priv | Shutdown_priv | Process_priv | File_priv | Grant_priv | References_priv | Index_priv | Alter_priv | Show_db_priv | Super_priv | Create_tmp_table_priv | Lock_tables_priv | Execute_priv | Repl_slave_priv | Repl_client_priv | Create_view_priv | Show_view_priv | Create_routine_priv | Alter_routine_priv | Create_user_priv | Event_priv | Trigger_priv | Create_tablespace_priv | ssl_type | ssl_cipher | x509_issuer | x509_subject | max_questions | max_updates | max_connections | max_user_connections | plugin                | authentication_string                     | password_expired | password_last_changed | password_lifetime | account_locked |
+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+-----------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------+--------------+------------------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+----------------+
| localhost | root      | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y         | Y           | Y             | Y            | Y         | Y          | Y               | Y          | Y          | Y            | Y          | Y                     | Y                | Y            | Y               | Y                | Y                | Y              | Y                   | Y                  | Y                | Y          | Y            | Y                      |          |            |             |              |             0 |           0 |               0 |                    0 | auth_socket           |                                           | N                | 2016-02-08 15:54:07   |              NULL | N              |
| localhost | mysql.sys | N           | N           | N           | N           | N           | N         | N           | N             | N            | N         | N          | N               | N          | N          | N            | N          | N                     | N                | N            | N               | N                | N                | N              | N                   | N                  | N                | N          | N            | N                      |          |            |             |              |             0 |           0 |               0 |                    0 | mysql_native_password | *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE | N                | 2016-02-08 15:54:08   |              NULL | Y              |
+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+-----------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------+--------------+------------------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

without any password require ?

I don't know why?

Comment: Can you try setting the password in mysql e.g. `UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('YOURNEWPASSWORD') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; exit;`

Comment: @Matt ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Password' in 'field list'.

Comment: Whoops, thinking of old versions. `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';`

Comment: @Matt I find the links maybe helpful .https://www.alextomkins.com/2014/07/mysql-unix-socket-authentication/

Answer (score 9):

I think the problem is the mysql.user in the column `plugin`, the variable name is auth_socket.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pluggable-authentication.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.5/en/socket-authentication-plugin.html

If you want to change the authentication of the mysql user, please follow the steps below:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED with mysql_native_password;
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

That should work.